# How to extending magento 1.9 RWD template

Tags: frontend

I would like to know the best approach on how to edit `frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`?

Is it possible that I don't touch this?

on the configuration "rwd" is set as a default theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create your own theme inside "rwd"

Lest say you call it **mytheme**. So your folder should be

```
rwd/mytheme/layout
rwd/mytheme/template
```

and in skin

```
rwd/mytheme/css
rwd/mytheme/js
rwd/mytheme/images
```

Now go to `System > Configuration > Design > Theme` section and save all field with **mytheme** in it.

Now simply copy any file from **rwd/default** or even from **base** to this folder in same folder structure, it should work.